# NSFetchedResultsController, CoreData, SectionIndex and special chars (Umlaute..)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data

I am having problems with NSFechtedResultsController and using the created sectionIndex(data is coming from a CoreData storage). It seems to mix up the indexTitle versus the sectionName e.g. sectionName is "Ä" and sectionIndex is "Ƒ" (0x0191) regarding the unicode char. This seems to be the case with all special chars. this can lead to crashes in case the user is able to use the special chars.

Is this is a known problem or does anyone know a workaround? Apple Addressbook app seems to collect all special cases under sectionIndex "#". Wondering if I should write a ton of code to workaround or if someone already did it? or just get rid of the section index.

thanks a lot.
Jens

Comment: Check fro my extended answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15587961/1791090

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: using `UILocalizedIndexedCollation` seems to be a possible solution. Trying to get it playing nice with core data and `NSFetchedResultsController` now.

--Jens

Comment: Well its not really answered. Getting UILocalizedIndexedCollation playing nice with NSFechtedResultsController and CoreData does not seem to be that easy.

Comment: Found this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167857/non-us-characters-in-section-headers-for-a-uitableview

So for just "FirstLetterOfName" Sections there is a solution. But I still dont know how to solve it for complete sectionInfoNames (e.g. Österreich).