# CoreData: NSSortDescriptor - Á to A, à to A (@selector)

Tags: core-data, nssortdescriptor

I'm using s selector (localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:), but i need also to use the Diacritic selector.

Code:

```
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CompanyActivity" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:descriptionLanguageKey
                                                                                     ascending:YES
                                                                                      selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
```

How can I use both?

Thanks,

RL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use UILocalizedIndexedCollation for doing sorting and categorizing entries into sections.  The code for implementing this is in the question [NSFetchedResultsController v.s. UILocalizedIndexedCollation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199934/nssearchresultscontroller-v-s-uilocalizedindexedcollation)

The UILocalizedIndexedCollation was built to be able to on a per-language basis categorize words based on the current language settings.  Á and à will be put in section A.

Comment: Because i want the á to be under the A section.