# CoreData: transient property and localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, transient

In coredata, i have a transient property to use has sections. The transient property code is here:

```
- (NSString *) firstLetter_transient {
[self willAccessValueForKey:@"firstLetter_transient"];
NSString *initial = [[[self memberName] substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString];
[self didAccessValueForKey:@"firstLetter_transient"];

return initial;
}
```

When I apply this, in Portuguese language, I get, for example "Á" has the first letter.

Question Nr 1: how can I put "Á" in the "A" section? I have an error with this:

"The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134060.)"

Question Nr 2: when it comes to numbers, how can I affect the numbers to section named "#"? Now, the number 1 creates a section "1", and so on.

Thanks all,

RL

Answer (score 1):

You should use UILocalizedIndexedCollation for doing sorting and categorizing entries into sections.  The code for implementing this is in the question [NSFetchedResultsController v.s. UILocalizedIndexedCollation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199934/nssearchresultscontroller-v-s-uilocalizedindexedcollation)

The UILocalizedIndexedCollation was built to be able to on a per-language basis categorize words based on the current language settings.  Á and à will be put in section A.