# How to sort non-english strings using nspredicate?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, nssortdescriptor

I am sorting results of a fetch request with a sort descriptor.

```
NSFetchRequest* req = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:[MyEntity entityName]];
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"property" 
                                                           ascending:YES 
                                                            selector:@selector(localizedCompare:)];
req.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor];
return [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:req error:nil];
```

The problem is the words, which begins with non-english chars like 'İ' are listed at the end of the list. It is a turkish letter and the alphabet looks like this :

> A, B, C, Ç, D, E, F, G, Ğ, H, I, İ, J, K, L, M, N, O, Ö, P, R, S, Ş, T, U, Ü, V, Y, Z.

So the letter is at 12th position.

I don't know why but using comparator after fetching objects works. So it works on any array but not with sort descriptor for fetch request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the details of my question at [NSFetchedResultsController v.s. UILocalizedIndexedCollation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199934/nssearchresultscontroller-v-s-uilocalizedindexedcollation) I show how to use the UILocalizedIndexedCollation to correctly generate the Alphabet and sort using the correct sort method based on the UILocalizedIndexCollation.  My question just revolves around asking for a better way to do this.

If you dont use the UILocalizedIndexCollation you should only use the localizedStandardCompare: not localizedCompare as mentioned in the WWDC videos for localization.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"property" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCompare:)]
```

**EDIT**

@Mert has updated his question. It seems now that `localizedCompare:` sorts the turkish letters correctly, but does not work with the fetch request.

Here is what I have done to test this problem. Perhaps you can check if that works in your environment and then work from there:

```
// Create some entities:
NSArray *a = @[@"İ", @"J", @"Ğ", @"G", @"H", @"I", @"Ç", @"C"];
for (NSString *s in a) {
    MyEntity *e = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyEntity"
                                                inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    e.name = s;
}

// Fetch all entities in sorted order:
NSFetchRequest* req = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"MyEntity"];
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name"
                                                           ascending:YES
                                                            selector:@selector(localizedCompare:)];
req.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor];
NSArray *result = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:req error:nil];
```

"MyEntity" is a Core Data entity with one attribute "name" of type String.

Comment: It didn't work. I also tried changing language of the simulator.

Comment: That is strange. If I sort an array with `[myArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCompare:)]` then I get correct results. Can you show the code how you setup the fetch request?

Comment: I have done it in almost the same way (with a fetched results controller), and it works for german umlauts and other international characters. Btw: Do you compile with ARC or not?

Comment: I already tried that but will ask again what was your Localization native development region in project settings? Yes I am compiling with ARC

Comment: Where does the localizedCompare function get the language?

Comment: 1. The Apple documentation on `localizedCompare:` is pretty vague on which localization it uses. For me it just worked. - 2. I do not set a "Localization native development region" in my project settings. The simulator Language is German and the Region is United States.

Comment: To localize the problem you could fetch the results first and then create a sorted array with `NSArray *sortedResults = [results sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCompare:)]` - just to find out where the problem lies: the comparison function or the fetch request.

Comment: Yes I edited my question and added that too. It works for array but not for a fetch request. Since I have like thousand entries, I am afraid of this may cause performance problems.

Comment: Is "property" a string attribute of your entity?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problems with :

`[strArr sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCompare:)]`

It seems that

`localizedCompare`

calls

`compare:other options:nil range:NSMakeRange(0, self.length) locale: [NSLocale currentLocale]];`

`[NSLocale currentLocale]` might be in a mixed state depending on the users preferences. It is therefor needed to create a clean `NSLocale` based on the users language

Try creating a category on `NSString` with the following content:

```
-(NSComparisonResult)currentLocalCompare:(id)other
{
    NSLocale * currLoc = [NSLocale currentLocale]; //get current locale
    NSLocale * loc = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:currLoc.localeIdentifier];//lets create a new clean NSLocale based on users prefared langauge
    return [self compare:other options:nil range:NSMakeRange(0, self.length) locale:loc];//compare using clean NSLocale
}
```

and call it like:

`[strArr sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(currentLocalCompare:)]`