# ios localized first character as section name

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, localization

I have been searching hours...

I wanted to implement section names with localized first letters as if apple's Contacts App.
If my phone setting is localized, that string will be in seperate section. if not it will be merged in related US characher.

In example,

In English settings: Ömer,Özgün,Orhan,Özüm will be in "O" section sort results in: Ömer,Özgün,Özüm,Orhan

In Turkish settings: Ömer,Özgün,Özüm will be in "Ö" section and Orhan will be in "O" section.

I have tried this: [How to use the first character as a section name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741093/how-to-use-the-first-character-as-a-section-name)

and many others...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `UILocalizedIndexedCollation`.