# UITableView sections / Each "name" is its own section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, sections

I need your help, this problem is driving me nuts! I'm trying to have my UITableView rows ordered alphabetically, but all I get, is that every row has it's own section, both named equally.

How can I solve this?

This is my code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [self.fetchedResultsController sectionIndexTitles];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    return [self.fetchedResultsController sectionForSectionIndexTitle:title atIndex:index];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo name];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ListCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    NSManagedObject *aPerson = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [aPerson valueForKey:@"name"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [aPerson valueForKey:@"number"];

    return cell;
}

// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext=[self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

        NSError *error;
        if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error saving after delete", @"Error saving after delete.")
                                                      message:[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Error was: %@, quitting.", @"Error was: %@,quitting."), [error localizedDescription]]
                                                     delegate:self
                                            cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Aw, Nuts", @"Aw, Nuts")
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObject *selectedHero = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DetailSegue" sender:selectedHero];
}

#pragma mark - FetchedResultsController Property

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Team"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSString *sectionKey = nil;

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"number" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, sortDescriptor2, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    sectionKey = @"name";

    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:sectionKey cacheName:@"Team"];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sure of this part of code?

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    return [self.fetchedResultsController sectionForSectionIndexTitle:title atIndex:index];
}
```

This generate a recursively loop.

Comment: based from NSFetchedResultController (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) it is correct.

Comment: I do not see a recursive loop here. The table view data source method `sectionForSectionIndexTitle` calls the fetched results controller method `sectionForSectionIndexTitle`.

Answer (score 0):

You have set the `sectionNameKeyPath` parameter of the fetched results controller to
`@"name"`, therefore the FRC creates one table view section for each name.

If you don't want sections, just set `sectionNameKeyPath:nil`.

If you want the names grouped into sections according to the *initial letter*,
set `sectionNameKeyPath` to a (transient) property of the entity that just contains
the initial letter of each object, as described e.g. here:
[How to use the first character as a section name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741093/how-to-use-the-first-character-as-a-section-name)