# How can I simply insert a date header when row is a different day on iOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView, where I'm adding data to a row using a nib file. I've just showing the the table, nothing happens if the user taps the row, its just a report.

However, I have lots of rows and some rows occur on the same date, I'd like to add a thin row to group these rows.

Can I do this within cellForRowAtIndexpath, if not how?

Here's my current code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ReportCell";

ReportCell *cell = (ReportCell *) [tableView 
        dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
        loadNibNamed:@"ReportCell"
        owner:nil options:nil];

    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
            cell = ((ReportCell *) currentObject);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this is probably with sections.

Take a look at

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index 

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Answer (score 0):

UITableView supports sections with headers.

This question/answer discuss how to use sectioned table views backed by Core Data:
[Core Data backed UITableView with indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599204/core-data-backed-uitableview-with-indexing)