# Fetch Predicate from Core Data Model into sections using NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I've been going around this question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599204/core-data-backed-uitableview-with-indexing/1603428#1603428)

And trying to implement my own solution. Somehow, I don't get any sections. Only rows.

3 rows in this case... But no Sections. There should be 2 sections at least. 2 Months. I know this because I inspected the model and they are there.

My **Core Data Model** has an entity **Year**, containing many months (Entity **Month**). And Month has also many days (Entity **Day**)

The attributes that represent each one individualy are, year_, month_ and day_, for the entities **Year**, **Month** and **Day**, respectively.

What I'm trying to do is a **fetch request to all days**, **in a given Month**, **in a Given Year** in a way that I can have my sections representing a Month and Rows representing Days.

Can someone help me out?

edit: updated code

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Day" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];


NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"day_" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];


[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                    managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext
                                      sectionNameKeyPath:@"month.month_"
                                               cacheName:@"Root"];
```

My model is looking like this,

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Nuno

Comment: What's stopping you from using sectionNameKeyPath based on the month name, with the primary sort descriptor being the order number of the month

Comment: Doesn't work. sectionNameKeyPath:@"month.month_" and initWithKey:@"month.month_" it doesn't get me any sections, whatsoever. Only the 3 rows that I already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"";

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Day" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Month.month_" ascending:NO];
NSSortDescriptor *sort2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"day_" ascending:NO];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sort,sort2]];

[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                    managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:"month.month_"
                                               cacheName:@"Root"];
```

Comment: First of all, Thank you very much for your help @dorada! I bet your code should work. I implemented it, but it's no good. I don't know why I don't get my sections. Do you happen to know if sectionNameKeyPath:"month.month_" can refer to a NSNumber in my model? Is this allowed? Or month_ property must be a NSString?

Comment: My problem wasn't here. I was not implementing - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section. After doing so, I got my sections displayed. I'm placing your answer as correct, because it is actually correct and it was indeed helpful nonetheless. Thank you =)

Answer (score 0):

Fetch it all at once and use a Dictionary of arrays to sort it after it's returned. So, you loop through the results and created an array for each section and store it the array in a dictionary indexed for each section. Your Dictionary would look like

```
{ 
 {'January", "1,2,6,19,23,nil"},
 {'February", "2,7,18,19,28,nil"},
 {'March", "5,6,7,9,29,31,nil"},
 etc.
}
```

There is a [good tutorial with code at icodeblog](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/12/10/implementing-uitableview-sections-from-an-nsarray-of-nsdictionary-objects/) that gives an example of the details needed to do this.

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion, but I'm really looking to use NSFetchedResultsController. Thank you @Mark